# Chef-solo unable to unzip .zip file

Tags: fedora, unzip, chef-solo, recipe

I have a zip file: ABC.zip. I am on Fedora 20.

In my chef recipe I intend to unzip as follows:

```
bash "Unzip ABC" do
  user "root"
  cwd "/opt/abc"
  code <<-EOH
    unzip -o ABC.zip
    cd ABC
    rm -f ABC.zip
  EOH
end
```

but when it comes to the point in the recipe it just hangs...

```
bash[Unzip ABC] action run
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been struggling with this for days...

Comment: Is there any out put in the chef run stack trace?

Comment: Could it also be that your bash code is indented, where as in the documentation the code start, and EOH are all in the same indent? https://docs.getchef.com/resource_bash.html#examples

Comment: Do you have zip installed?